# Wordpress: Overriding a function in a derived class

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, overriding

I need to override the function `adforest_profile_full_top()` from `profile.php`. This function is in a class called `adforest_profile`.

I added this code in my `function.php`:

```php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() {

  class Myclass extends adforest_profile {

    function adforest_profile_full_top() {
      //original function code with my custom modifications      
    }   

  }   
  new Myclass();
});
```

With this, I received the following error:

> Parse error syntax error unexpected '$user_pic'

This is the parent PHP file that contains the function I want to override:

```php
<?php
if (!class_exists('adforest_profile')) {

    class adforest_profile {

// user object
        var $user_info;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
        }

// Full Width Profile Top
        function adforest_profile_full_top() {
$user_pic = adforest_get_user_dp($this->user_info->ID, 'adforest-user-profile');
//and more code...
}

}
}

?>
```

Can you give me a good way to override this function in my `function.php` file? I don't want to override the entire class, just one function inside the class. Thank you.

Comment: `var $user_info;` declaration is incorrect in php, it should be `private $user_info;`.

Comment: Ok tahnk you but this is not my code...But I don't think it helps about the topic ?